# Cost of Custom Exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

I've read that throwing exceptions is an expensive operation.  However, doesn't creating your own exceptions make your code more expressive and readable?

Some of my coworkers suggest that you should just use System.Exception and insert your custom text into the message instead of creating a new custom exception.

I'm interested in other opinions.  Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Ummm, how are throwing exceptions and defining your own exception classes related...? Whether you use `System.Exception` or derive from it or some other built-in class, you're gonna have to throw it anyway so the expense is on actually generating and throwing the exceptions. Not writing them.

Comment: Your coworker is pulling your leg or - if not - hopefully won't be your coworker much longer.

Comment: Unless... they meant it costs more man-minutes to write custom classes then throw them, than to just use the built-in ones from the get-go. In which case... lol.

Comment: As far as I can tell, custom exceptions aren't for sale: [http://shop.ebay.com/](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=custom+exception&_sacat=See-All-Categories)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not throw `System.Exception`. Ever.

The problem with it resides in the calling code. It is a bad practice to catch the general `Exception` object for many reasons. If you throw an instance of the `Exception` base class, then calling code has no choice but to catch `Exception` if they want to handle it. This forces the calling code to use a bad practice.

Also, the calling code has no reliable means of distinguishing what the exception was, if all it gets is `Exception`.

It is typically best to use one of the pre-defined exceptions if any are applicable (`ArgumentException`, `InvalidOperationException`, etc.). If none correctly describe the situation, then a custom exception class is a perfectly good way to go.

Comment: In cases where there's nothing reasonable to do apart from logging the exception, and there's no suitable BCL exception at hand (though that's unlikely), throwing `Exception` is better than creating an otherwise pointless custom exception.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you ever written code to catch an `ArgumentException`?

Comment: @Jeff Sternal - In that case, it is more appropriate to throw an  `ApplicationException`.

Comment: @Jeffrey - I'm not convinced that adds any value, similar to how MS no longer suggests deriving custom exceptions from `ApplicationException` ("It was originally thought that custom exceptions should derive from the ApplicationException class; however in practice this has not been found to add significant value. For more information, see Best Practices for Handling Exceptions.")

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge: Since the only reason you give for not throwing `Exception` is so that people can catch your exception separately from others, then what is the advantage to throwing an `ArgumentException` instead? I just don't feel like the reasoning given here merits the hard-line approach you're advocating. (Edit: I'm not saying you should never throw an `ArgumentException`--I'm just saying that it's maybe a bit much to never *ever* throw an `Exception`.)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - When you look in your log file and find an ArgumentException there, then you know immediately that somebody deserves to be made fun of. Exception types can help in diagnostics as well as program flow, so more specific exceptions are always to be preferred.

Comment: Throwing a bare Exception is a classic "harmless" short-cut, that has hidden long-term consequences related to future API usability, tooling options, etc. Why not just follow best-practices?

Comment: @Jeff Sternal - Maybe you know that your exception will never, ever need to be caught. But to take away from me forever the *option* of handling it would be extremely annoying.

Comment: I understand that simply having a specific type associated with certain types of exceptions can have diagnostic value, and in those cases I'm all for using a custom exception. I also appreciate the importance of keeping an eye toward the possible long-term uses, etc. On the other hand, I've seen a lot of cases where a custom exception type is just one more class to maintain (and keep bug-free), and I've never seen any hidden consequences pop up from using an `Exception` (or `InvalidOperationException`--what's the difference?) in these cases. A good message is far more crucial for dianostics.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I am not arguing for custom exceptions, which I use only very rarely. I am arguing against using the base Exception class. `InvalidOperationException` is a great choice for an exception. But even so, custom exception types are remarkably easy to maintain, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It's the overhead of throwing an exception itself (creating the object, walking the stack, etc.) that's costly. Making your own exception class adds almost no overhead, so if you're going to throw an exception, **don't** make it `new Exception("message")`!

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions aren't meant to be read by people (though their messages and stack traces are read by people), they're meant to be read by code. If there's something your code can do in response to a custom exception, by all means go for it. But the exception is just destined to be logged, there's no point to making a custom one.

The overhead of custom exceptions is that they're another thing to maintain and test. If an existing exception is suitable, use that instead. (E.g., `ArgumentNullException` instead of `ZipCodeNullException`.)

Answer (score 1):

1. If there's any reason for your exception to be caught and handled differently from standard Exceptions, then you should create your own class.
2. If there's any reason for your exception to take different arguments (e.g. to produce a specially-formatted message based on a set of arguments that you're often likely to have), then you should create your own class.

In any other case, you're safe just using `Exception`. Generally speaking, it doesn't really cost any more to instantiate or throw a custom exception than a standard one, at least not compared with the expense of throwing an exception in the first place. Exceptions, by definition, should be exceptional, and therefore performance during the throwing of an exception is a non-issue. The point is to have all the information you need when the time comes to look at why that exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Your coworker is talking nonsense. Throwing an exception is the same cost regardless of the class.

And to be honest, all this talk of "expensive" exceptions - yes they are more expensive than a null check or some such, so don't ever use them as a replacement for some sanity check, but they should be encouraged where they make sense (like IOException for example, that's an excellent use case for them - problems with I/O are an exceptional case and they usually must be handled outside of normal program flow).

Comment: Instantiating an exception isn't particularly costly; throwing it is.

Comment: It's no more costly if its custom or not - the throw operation is type agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

You should never throw a `System.Exception`, because then the only way to catch is is by `catch(System.Exception)`. It's very bad practice to catch a blanket exception like that. You should catch specific exceptions, which give you a way to properly handle it without crashing the software. By generating custom exceptions, you give yourself a way to potentially recognize and recover from them.

For example, if your code means to open a file, and you get an unknown exception, how do you recover from it? However, if you catch a specific File Not Found exception, that is much easier to recover from. You can tell the user definitively that the file doesn't exist.

I don't see a reason to believe that custom exceptions are any more expensive than the built-in ones.

Answer (score 0):

"Expensive" is a relative term and - as the name already suggests - an exception should be an exception, so it will probably not affect the performance of your code. The cost of throwing an exception is - as far as I know - independent of the type of the exception, so you should not restrict yourself to System.Exception.

But most important: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the most appropriate built in exception, and if that doesn't already exist,  derive my own from System.ApplicationException.

I wouldn't recommend throwing System.Exception with a custom message.